# Multiple sites routed to one codebase has the subdirectory name as prefix on the links

Tags: uri

I am trying to redirect multiple drupal sites to same code base using following htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?site.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdirectory/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdirectory/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?ngeneric.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subdirectory/index.php [L]
```

It workds but, now every URL on the site has its subdirectory infront like

> http://site.com/**subdirectory**/.....

How to fix this?

**More Info:** Domain is routed to `public_html/a/` The drupal site in inside this `a` directory as `public_html/a/b` and I am trying to use multiple sites, so I am getting this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the `$baseurl` variable in settings.php, at Drupal site directory. Read the documentation around this variable in the settings file.

Comment: Yes I did try that too. No use